# don't show again ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode

In my app, I created a first ViewController (in storyboard) called welcome, with all the instructions. At the end of the page, I wanted to insert a box that could be selected showing "don't show again". By clicking on this box, and going to the next page, the first viewController will vanish. When I reopen the app, the controller won't be shown again. The only way to show it is by going on settings and selecting the switch "repristinate original settings" or something like that. Please, can anyone help me? Thanks!

I found an example but is not what I want:

```
- (IBAction)leggi{
NSString *stringaTesto = campo.text;
testo.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", stringaTesto];

NSString *testoInserito = testo.text;
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:testoInserito forKey:@"ciao"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

}

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *testoSalvato = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"ciao"];
    if (testoSalvato == nil) {
        testo.text = @"Non hai ancora inserito il tuo nome";
        } else {
        testo.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Ciao %@", testoSalvato];
        }

```
}
```

The IB Outlet is linked to a button

Answer (score 2):

store the **don't show again** as a `BOOL` in `NSUserDefaults`.. and check it before showing the view..

if it is TRUE..dont show.other wise show it.

> edit

Lets say you have your app delegate and currently show your don't show view again (Lets say A) from it ..after which you show another view(Lets say B)

then in your app delegate you have to get a BOOL

like this

```
BOOL _Dont_Show_Again = [NSUSerDefaults standardDefaults] boolForkey : @"Don't Show"];

if(_Dont_Show_Again)
{
load B Code here...
}
else
{
load A Code here;
}
```

first time _Dont_Show_Again will be 0 since it does not exist in default..but if user select don't show you should save it in the default and this code will then work fine for you

Comment: Sorry, but I am new to Objective C, can you please explain me more clearly? Thanks

Comment: look up tutorials on NSUserDefaults..it will easy after going through them,,ask if you are stuck on some portion..what you are asking is the whole process...and we don't do tutorials..only Q/A on stack overflow..

Comment: No way. I understood how to save text, as you can see in the edit of my question, but not how to hide a view controller

Comment: trying to understand...but i noticed that if I wand a ViewController to be linked to the codes (load A), I can't. I can only link the UIView

Comment: so don't link UIView in one case and link UIView in another